# FFMPEG - Could not load font "C": - Cannot escape semi colon

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro with ffmpeg 64 bit static build, trying to run the following cmd

```
"C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "C:\ffmpeg\v.mp4" -preset veryslow -crf 22 
-vf "drawtext=fontfile=C:/Windows/Fonts/Arial/ariblk.ttf: text='%
{localtime}': x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1" 
"o.mp4"
```

Which is returning the error

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0000000004c5cf20] Could not load font "C": cannot open resource
```

It seems the problem is around this part of the code which is caused by the semi colon : terminating the string.

```
fontfile=C:/Windows/Fonts/Arial/ariblk.ttf:
```

However, I have tried to escape it with backslahses in the following ecerpts but the error still exists

```
fontfile=C\:/Windows/Fonts/Arial/ariblk.ttf:
```

error

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0000000004c5cf20] Could not load font "C": cannot open resource
```

And

```
fontfile=C/:/Windows/Fonts/Arial/ariblk.ttf
```

error

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0000000004c5cf20] Could not load font "C/": cannot open resource
```

Lastly

```
fontfile='C:'/Windows/Fonts/Arial/ariblk.ttf
```

error

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0000000004c5cf20] Could not load font "C": cannot open resource
```

How can I get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
fontfile=C\\:\\\\Windows\\\\Fonts\\\\ariblk.ttf
```

There are several problems to address:

You will need to escape `:` with `\\:` as well as escape `\` with `\\\\`

The second part is how Windows appears to handle the location of the fonts. You might would think that the fonts are under a folder named Arial but they are actually just grouped to look that way in Explorer. The actual path for Arial Black in the root of Fonts. `c:\Windows\Fonts\ariblk.tff`

Comment: +1 perfect. Same concept trying to enter time duration as a parameter => -vf 'fade=in:st=0:d=2,fade=out:st=30\\:24:d=2'

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to escape the escape...

```
fontfile=C\\:/Windows/...
```

Credit goes to here:
https://superuser.com/questions/589214/ffmpeg-drawtext-initialization-error

Which in turn gives credit to: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2166

Answer (score 0):

```
"drawtext=fontfile='c\:/Windows/fonts/ariblk.ttf': ...
```

or

```
"drawtext=fontfile='c\:\\Windows\\fonts\\ariblk.ttf': ...
```